# What is the best way to get the percentage for an object in linq list and map it to JSON?

Tags: c#, json, linq, list

As a result of a `join` in `linq`  I am getting a list of RoleViewModel objects. What I want to do after is to get the percentage for each WorkRole in the list and map the work role's percentage and it's name to a json.

So, if I have  two objects total in  `var list` - one has RoleName "Role1" and the other has RoleName "Role2", what's the best way to get a JSON like :

```
myObj = {
    "rolename":"Role1",
    "perc":50
    },
  {
    "rolename":"Role2",
    "perc":50
    },
```

Here is the query for my list :

```
var list= list1.
                    Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
                    o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
                    (o, od) => new
                    {
                        WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                        RoleName = o.RoleName,
                        RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                        CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                        WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                        UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                        FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                        FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
                    }).ToList()
                    .Select(item => new RoleViewModel(
                       item.WorkRoleId,
                        item.RoleName,
                        item.RoleDescription,
                        item.CompanyId,
                        item.WRUDId,
                        item.UserDetailsId,
                        item.FocusStart,
                        item.FocusEnd)).ToList();
```

So, any tips on how can I do what I want in the best and easiest way? I am new to c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work like that:

```
var perclist = list.GroupBy(i=>i.RoleName)
      .Select(i=> 
            new { 
                 rolename=i.Key, 
                 perc = ((double)(i.Count()) / (double)(list.Count()) )*100
            });
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(perclist);
```

I user Json.NET for serialization

Comment: Thanks alot, great answer! :)